# Difference between Metric Space and Topological Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, self-learning

I am reading Chapter 11 of Real Analysis written by Royden and Patrick (4th). It says "The concept of uniform convergence of a sequence of functions is a metric concept. The concept of pointwise convergence is NOT a metric concept." (page 222) I know the definitions for uniform and pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions. However, I could not understand the quote above. Could anyone explain it to me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Try to write down definition of uniform convergence when you do not have metric spaces as domain or range. If you cannot, then you see what the difference is. If you can, something is wrong with your definitions.

Comment: The notion of pointwise convergence can be defined on a topological set. Namely, a sequence of points $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ in $X$ converges to $x\in X$ if every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains all but finitely many of the $x_i$. The definition of uniform convergence requires the use of a metric, and its generalization to topological spaces requires the notion of a [uniformity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: The domain needs no structure at all, it need not even be a topological space, @studiosus. Only the codomain.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was thinking about uniform continuity for some reason.

Comment: You should note that the totality of all maps $f\colon X\to Y$ is just the product space $Y^X$, and the pointwise convergence is just the convergence in the product space with product topology.

Answer (score -2):

Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions implies convergence of the sequence in the metric space of all functions.So it is a  metric concept.

Comment: This is quite a brief answer for a Question that has been around for almost three years.  At a minimum you should explain for the benefit of Readers what you mean by "the metric space of all functions" and why uniform convergence (of a sequence of functions) relates to this additional notion of convergence/topology.